# Create array from MYSQLI table in PHP and pass to JAVASCRIPT to allow autocomplete on form

Tags: javascript, php

I am using Bootstrap and I want to populate a PHP variable array using a MYSQL table value and then pass the array to a JAVASCRIPT variable to be able to use autocomplete but I just cannot get it to work. I know the PHP array is populated but I cannot see if the JAVASCRIPT variable is set up. Below is my code (excluding the call to the database)

```php
<?php
    $query1 = "SELECT country_code FROM country";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query1);
    if ($result1) { 
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
    }
    while( $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result1)){
      $addr_a[] = $row1['country_code']; 
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var addr_aray= <?php echo json_encode($addr_a); ?>;
   for(var i = 0; i < addr_aray.length; i++){
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = addr_aray;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: just modify this line to : document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = addr_aray[i];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Since you applied loop then you have to use array element inside loop, not whole array

B) You want to append each data to previous data, so use `+=` otherwise each new entry will remove older entries

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += addr_aray[i];
```

Comment: Thanks, It was a stupid mistake by me but then, I am learning. If i execute this program I do not get any output on the screen and I would like to know if the array is set up correctly (the PHP variable is there as I have checked that with echo

Comment: @HennyBotha  that can have multiple reasons. Try to make error reporting on and check what error you are facing. As well as try to check browser console for possible jQuery errors. In case you got the issue an unable to solve it, then ask a new question then.

Comment: Thanks again, I found the problem. The JQuery part was refering to "demo" and "demo" was not there so i just created a <div  id"demo"> and added a ','  in the while loop and it now works fine